# Understanding the functor category $\text{C}^X$ for $X$ a discrete set

Tags: category-theory, definition

From Mac Lane's Category Theory:

> Let $C$ be a category and let $X$ be a discrete set and let $A = \text{C}^X$ be the functor category.
>
> Then $A$ has as its objects the $X$-indexed families $a = \{a_x : x \in X\}$ of objects of $C$.

I'm having a difficult time seeing how the objects of $A$ are $x$-indexed families of $C$.

If a functor $(F : X \rightarrow \text{C})$ is an object of $A$, then it's defined entirely on where it sends each $x \in X$.  So I can see how an object of $A$ should be a collection of objects of $C$ that are defined by the particular functor $F$, i.e., an object of $A$ should be $a_F = \{c \in C : F(x) = c\ \text{for some $x \in X$}\}$.

But I'm not seeing how the objects are $x$ indexed families.

Can someone explain what I'm missing in the analogy here?

Comment: I guess you mean $C=\operatorname{Set}$?

Comment: I mistyped that, $C$ should just be a category, not one in particular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the functor $F$ and its image in $C$.

Just like a function $f:X\to Y$ between sets is not the set $\{y\in Y\,|\, f(x)=y \text{ for some } x\in X\}$, a functor $F:X\to C$ is not $\{c\in C\,|\, F(x)=c \text{ for some } x\in X\}$.

Rather, $F:X\to C$ is the association of some $c\in C$ for each $x\in X$, so we may write $c_x\in C$ for this particular element, and this gives a family $\{c_x\in C\,|\, x\in X\}$. The fact that $X$ is discrete as a category implies that the functor is determined by just this family (there is no need to worry about the action on morphisms).

Comment: So it's essentially: $c = c_F = \{c_x \in C | x \in X, \text{with the transformation $F(x) = c_x$}\}$?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "transformation". When $X$ is discrete, a functor $F:X\to C$ is the same thing as a simple function from the set $X$ to the set of objects of $C$. A function is the same thing as a family (by definition).

Comment: I will be more clear.  What I mean is: each object is a functor, and each set indexed by $x$ depends on the functor chosen.

Comment: You should rather say "indexed by $X$", but yes.